# Why is terraform forcing replacement of aurora global database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

#### Terraform CLI and Terraform AWS Provider Version

- Installed from https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.13.5/terraform_0.13.5_linux_amd64.zip
- hashicorp/aws v3.15.0

#### Affected Resource(s)

- aws_rds_cluster
- aws_rds_cluster_instance

#### Terraform Configuration Files

```
    # inside ./modules/rds/main.tf

    terraform {
      required_providers {
        aws = {
          source = "hashicorp/aws"
        }
      }
      required_version = "~> 0.13"
    }
    
    provider "aws" {
      alias = "primary"
    }
    
    provider "aws" {
      alias = "dr"
    }
    
    locals {
      region_tags      = ["primary", "dr"]
      db_name          = "${var.project_name}-${var.stage}-db"
      db_cluster_0     = "${local.db_name}-cluster-${local.region_tags[0]}"
      db_cluster_1     = "${local.db_name}-cluster-${local.region_tags[1]}"
      db_instance_name = "${local.db_name}-instance"
    }
    
    resource "aws_rds_global_cluster" "global_db" {
      global_cluster_identifier = "${var.project_name}-${var.stage}"
      database_name             = "${var.project_name}${var.stage}db"
      engine                    = "aurora-mysql"
      engine_version            = "${var.mysql_version}.mysql_aurora.${var.aurora_version}"
      // force_destroy             = true
    }
    
    resource "aws_rds_cluster" "primary_cluster" {
      depends_on         = [aws_rds_global_cluster.global_db]
      provider           = aws.primary
      cluster_identifier = "${local.db_name}-cluster-${local.region_tags[0]}"
    
      # the database name does not allow dashes:
      database_name = "${var.project_name}${var.stage}db"
    
      # The engine and engine_version must be repeated in aws_rds_global_cluster,
      # aws_rds_cluster, and aws_rds_cluster_instance to 
      # avoid "Value for engine should match" error
      engine                    = "aurora-mysql"
      engine_version            = "${var.mysql_version}.mysql_aurora.${var.aurora_version}"
      engine_mode               = "global"
      global_cluster_identifier = aws_rds_global_cluster.global_db.id
    
      # backtrack and multi-master not supported by Aurora Global.
    
      master_username         = var.username
      master_password         = var.password
      backup_retention_period = 5
      preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
      db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.primary.id
    
      # We must have these values, because destroying or rolling back requires them
      skip_final_snapshot       = true
      final_snapshot_identifier = "ci-aurora-cluster-backup"
    
      tags = {
        Name      = local.db_cluster_0
        Stage     = var.stage
        CreatedBy = var.created_by
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "primary" {
      depends_on           = [aws_rds_global_cluster.global_db]
      provider             = aws.primary
      cluster_identifier   = aws_rds_cluster.primary_cluster.id
      engine               = "aurora-mysql"
      engine_version       = "${var.mysql_version}.mysql_aurora.${var.aurora_version}"
      instance_class       = "db.${var.instance_class}.${var.instance_size}"
      db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.primary.id
    
      tags = {
        Name      = local.db_instance_name
        Stage     = var.stage
        CreatedBy = var.created_by
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_rds_cluster" "dr_cluster" {
      depends_on         = [aws_rds_cluster_instance.primary, aws_rds_global_cluster.global_db]
      provider           = aws.dr
      cluster_identifier = "${local.db_name}-cluster-${local.region_tags[1]}"
    
      # db name now allowed to specified on secondary regions
    
      # The engine and engine_version must be repeated in aws_rds_global_cluster,
      # aws_rds_cluster, and aws_rds_cluster_instance to 
      # avoid "Value for engine should match" error
      engine                    = "aurora-mysql"
      engine_version            = "${var.mysql_version}.mysql_aurora.${var.aurora_version}"
      engine_mode               = "global"
      global_cluster_identifier = aws_rds_global_cluster.global_db.id
    
      # backtrack and multi-master not supported by Aurora Global.
    
      # cannot specify username/password in cross-region replication cluster:
      backup_retention_period = 5
      preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
      db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.dr.id
    
      # We must have these values, because destroying or rolling back requires them
      skip_final_snapshot       = true
      final_snapshot_identifier = "ci-aurora-cluster-backup"
    
      tags = {
        Name      = local.db_cluster_1
        Stage     = var.stage
        CreatedBy = var.created_by
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "dr_instance" {
      depends_on           = [aws_rds_cluster_instance.primary, aws_rds_global_cluster.global_db]
      provider             = aws.dr
      cluster_identifier   = aws_rds_cluster.dr_cluster.id
      engine               = "aurora-mysql"
      engine_version       = "${var.mysql_version}.mysql_aurora.${var.aurora_version}"
      instance_class       = "db.${var.instance_class}.${var.instance_size}"
      db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.dr.id
    
      tags = {
        Name      = local.db_instance_name
        Stage     = var.stage
        CreatedBy = var.created_by
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "primary" {
      name       = "${local.db_name}-subnetgroup"
      subnet_ids = var.subnet_ids
      provider   = aws.primary
    
      tags = {
        Name      = "primary_subnet_group"
        Stage     = var.stage
        CreatedBy = var.created_by
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "dr" {
      provider   = aws.dr
      name       = "${local.db_name}-subnetgroup"
      subnet_ids = var.dr_subnet_ids
    
      tags = {
        Name      = "dr_subnet_group"
        Stage     = var.stage
        CreatedBy = var.created_by
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "default" {
      name        = "rds-cluster-pg"
      family      = "aurora-mysql${var.mysql_version}"
      description = "RDS default cluster parameter group"
      parameter {
        name  = "character_set_server"
        value = "utf8"
      }
      parameter {
        name  = "character_set_client"
        value = "utf8"
      }
      parameter {
        name         = "aurora_parallel_query"
        value        = "ON"
        apply_method = "pending-reboot"
      }
    }
```

Inside `./modules/sns/main.tf`, this is the resource I'm adding when calling `terraform apply` from within the `./modules` directory:

```
    resource "aws_sns_topic" "foo_topic" {
      name = "foo-${var.stage}-${var.topic_name}"
      tags = {
        Name      = "foo-${var.stage}-${var.topic_name}"
        Stage     = var.stage
        CreatedBy = var.created_by
        CreatedOn = timestamp()
      }
    }
```

`./modules/main.tf`:

```
    terraform {
      backend "s3" {
        bucket = "terraform-remote-state-s3-bucket-unique-name"
        key    = "terraform.tfstate"
        region = "us-east-2"
        dynamodb_table = "TerraformLockTable"
      }
    }

    provider "aws" {
      alias  = "primary"
      region = var.region
    }

    provider "aws" {
      alias  = "dr"
      region = var.dr_region
    }


    module "vpc" {
      stage  = var.stage
      source = "./vpc"
      providers = {
        aws = aws.primary
      }
    }
    module "dr_vpc" {
      stage  = var.stage
      source = "./vpc"
      providers = {
        aws = aws.dr
      }
    }

    module "vpc_security_group" {
      source = "./vpc_security_group"
      vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
      providers = {
        aws = aws.primary
      }
    }


    module "rds" {
      source        = "./rds"
      stage         = var.stage
      created_by    = var.created_by
      vpc_id        = module.vpc.vpc_id
      subnet_ids    = [module.vpc.subnet_a_id, module.vpc.subnet_b_id, module.vpc.subnet_c_id]
      dr_subnet_ids = [module.dr_vpc.subnet_a_id, module.dr_vpc.subnet_b_id, module.dr_vpc.subnet_c_id]
      region        = var.region
      username      = var.rds_username
      password      = var.rds_password

      providers = {
        aws.primary = aws.primary
        aws.dr      = aws.dr
      }
    }

    module "sns_start" {
      stage      = var.stage
      source     = "./sns"
      topic_name = "start"
      created_by = var.created_by
    }
```

`./modules/variables.tf`:

```
variable "region" {
  default = "us-east-2"
}

variable "dr_region" {
  default = "us-west-2"
}
variable "service" {
  type        = string
  default     = "foo-back"
  description = "service to match what serverless framework deploys"
}

variable "stage" {
  type        = string
  default     = "sandbox"
  description = "The stage to deploy: sandbox, dev, qa, uat, or prod"

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("sandbox|dev|qa|uat|prod", var.stage))
    error_message = "The stage value must be a valid stage: sandbox, dev, qa, uat, or prod."
  }
}

variable "created_by" {
  description = "Company or vendor name followed by the username part of the email address"
}

variable "rds_username" {
  description = "Username for rds"
}

variable "rds_password" {
  description = "Password for rds"
}
```

`./modules/sns/main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "foo_topic" {
  name = "foo-${var.stage}-${var.topic_name}"
  tags = {
    Name      = "foo-${var.stage}-${var.topic_name}"
    Stage     = var.stage
    CreatedBy = var.created_by
    CreatedOn = timestamp()
  }
}
```

`./modules/sns/output.tf`:

```
output "sns_topic_arn" {
  value = aws_sns_topic.foo_topic.arn
}
```

#### Debug Output

Both outputs have modified keys, names, account IDs, etc:

- The `plan` output from running `terraform apply`:
  https://gist.github.com/ystoneman/95df711ee0a11d44e035b9f8f39b75f3
- The `state` before applying: https://gist.github.com/ystoneman/5c842769c28e1ae5969f9aaff1556b37

#### Expected Behavior

The entire `./modules/main.tf` had already been created, and the only thing that was added was the SNS module, so only the SNS module should be created.

#### Actual Behavior

But instead, the RDS resources are affected too, and terraform "claims" that `engine_mode` has changed from `provisioned` to `global`, even though it already was `global` according to the console:

The `plan` output also says that `cluster_identifier` is only `known after apply` and therefore `forces replacement`, however, I think the `cluster_identifier` is necessary to let the `aws_rds_cluster` know it belongs to the `aws_rds_global_cluster`, and for the `aws_rds_cluster_instance` to know it belongs to the `aws_rds_cluster`, respectively.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. comment out the `module "sns_start"`
2. cd `./modules`
3. `terraform apply` (after this step is done is where the state file I included is at)
4. uncomment out the `module "sns_start"`
5. `terraform apply` (at this point is where I provide the debug output)

#### Important Factoids

This problem happens whether I run it from my Mac or within AWS CodeBuild.

#### References

Seems like [AWS Terraform tried to destory and rebuild RDS cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372050/aws-terraform-tried-to-destory-and-rebuild-rds-cluster) references this too, but it's not specific to a Global Cluster, where you do need identifiers so that instances and clusters know to what they belong to.

Comment: Before terraform does anything it tells you what it is going to do, asks for confirmation and it explains based on what property change it will destroy / recreate a resource. What does that output tell you?

Comment: As mentioned above, you would need to edit your question to include the output of the plan for this to be answerable.

Comment: @luk2302, I added a lot more detail, including gist links to the plan output.

Comment: The plan output you linked clearly indicates why it's destroying/recreating the resources. Look at the lines that say `# forces replacement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using an outdated version of the aws provider and are specifying the `engine_mode` incorrectly. There was a bug ticket relating to this: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16088
It is fixed in version 3.15.0 which you can use via

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.15.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = "~> 0.13"
}
```

Additionally you should drop the `engine_mode` property from your terraform specification completely.